# Actionscript 3 Air iOS POST data not sending with URLLoader

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, post, air, urlloader

I have the following code to send POST data to my server:

```
var headers:Array = [
    new URLRequestHeader("api_access_token", ACCESS_TOKEN),
    new URLRequestHeader("api_secret", SECRET),
    new URLRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json")
];
var base_url = "http://example.com/";
var complete_func:Function;

function postRequest(url:String, params:Object, response_func:Function){
    complete_func = response_func;
    var request = new URLRequest(base_url+url);
    request.requestHeaders = headers;
    request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
    request.contentType = "application/json";
    request.data = JSON.stringify(params);

    //  Handlers
    var postLoader = new URLLoader();
    postLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, parseResponse);
    postLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, function(e:IOErrorEvent){ trace(e); });
    postLoader.load(request);
}

function parseResponse(e:Event){
    var data = e.target.data;
    trace(data);
    var json_data = JSON.parse(data);
    complete_func(json_data);
}
```

Problem is, on my server, when I use `var_dump($_POST)` nothing but an empty array is returned. I don't know why this is the case. I have done `traces` on `params` and `url` parameters which contain relavent data.

The params I am sending are:

```
var customerDetails:Object = new Object();
    customerDetails.first_name = firstNameField.text;
    customerDetails.last_name = lastNameField.text;
    customerDetails.dob = dobField.text;
    customerDetails.email = emailField.text;
```

The headers retrieved by PHP's `list_headers()` returns:

```
array(6) { [0]=> string(24) "X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.30" [1]=> string(38) "Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT" [2]=> string(77) "Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0" [3]=> string(16) "Pragma: no-cache" [4]=> string(44) "api_secret: example_secret" [5]=> string(50) "api_access_token: example_access" }
```

I am using Air 16.0 for iOS with ActionScript 3

Any help would be great. I don't know if this is a cross-domain policy issue.

P.S. Works fine with a GET request.

Answer (score 0):

Use the right `dataFormat`:

```
loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES
```

Comment: When I change that, I get the following error: `The String passed to URLVariables.decode() must be a URL-encoded query string containing name/value pairs.`. But I'm not calling `URLVariables.decode()`.

Comment: Just to test: change your php to one line: `echo $_POST` and look what coming in in your loader.data.

Comment: Nothing, there is nothing coming into $_POST or $_REQUEST. It works fine when I use `request.method = URLRequestMethod.GET` but that's $_GET, which is not what I want to achieve.

Comment: Even more strangely, the Apache access log has a POST entry: `92.40.248.198 - - [09/Jun/2015:11:10:59 +0100] "POST /customers/new/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1968 "app:/registration.swf" "Mozilla/5.0 (iOS; U; en) AppleWebKit/533.19.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) AdobeAIR/16.0"`

Comment: that means, there was a POST coming in? Whats about your headers? Just to test, dont attach them. Generally to test I would start with a simple simple simple request to figure out where the problem occurs.

Comment: The headers are working for `api_secret_token` and `api_acces_token`, but maybe I need to set the content type in the `URLRequestHeader` instead of `URLRequest.contentType`. I'll try that now.

Comment: The headers I get from PHP's `list_headers()` are: `array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(24) "X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.30"
  [1]=>
  string(38) "Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT"
  [2]=>
  string(77) "Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0"
  [3]=>
  string(16) "Pragma: no-cache"
  [4]=>
  string(44) "api_secret: example_secret"
  [5]=>
  string(50) "api_access_token: example_access"
}`. It appears `new URLRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json")` doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

As3 code is valid. You need improve from server side php code.. Please try this ..

```
<?php 

$body = @file_get_contents('php://input');
$jsn =  json_decode($body);
echo $jsn->first_name;
echo $jsn->last_name;
echo $jsn->dob;
echo $jsn->email;

?>
```